# How to send colour coded alerts from cloudera CDH?

Tags: json, cloudera-cdh

We are receiving numerous alerts from cloudera CDH, and we would like to segregate them on the basis of colour codes, so that we can look into actionable items at once? Is there any way in cloudera to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color codes are not available in CDH, the default color are **red for bad, yellow for warning and green for good** health. But you can create your own custom alert script refer below link

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cm_ag_alert_script.html

Comment: Thanks for the information. Mail categorization was the goal. This thread helped more on configuring custom mail subjects : [link]https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/How-to-change-subject-prefix-for-email-alerts/m-p/40945#M7314